# Can I used variable with( paddin : EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0) ) instead (8.0) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I noticed that when u write const `EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0)` it good,but when you want to add variable instead of `(8.0)` will not able to do that when you write `const`..

For examle:

`final screenHeight=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;`

padding:  `EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight*0.2131336)` (correct code)

padding: `const EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight*0.2131336)` (wrong code)

Is this good way to make the padding more flexible to difference size of screen .Or there are wigdet perform the perfect .
Notice that I used Stack widget so the space must be fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `const` instance can improve performance because just one instance is ever created. That single instance gets used whenever you need an inset of exactly 8. For `const` to work everything must be known at compile time.

As soon as you introduce a variable, it's no longer fixed at compile time and must be computed at runtime. The instance of `EdgeInsets` will get created on the heap and garbage collected after it is used. That's why it cannot be marked `const`. Note that Flutter is designed to perform well even when class instances have to be created at runtime and garbage collected, so introducing a variable should have a negligible effect.

Comment: Thanks.So if I write variable instead (8.0) it will be work carefully or not ?